# How do I Trace a Dsl/DslPackage at run-time (Visual Studio VS2012)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dsl, vsix, vspackage, dsl-tools

How do I trace a VS2012 DSL/DSL Package VSIX at run-time.
I have an odd bug with an error message, "Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'" and I guess it's something to do with deserializing the XML written by the DSL.

Although I can add breakpoints in the DSL code while debugging in the Exp Instance, the code is so event driven that it is difficut to find the cause.

I don't want to litter the code with Trace.Writeline statements.
Instead I'd like to monitor what the application is doing to get a stack trace or similar. I know this sort of thing is possible with Unix, but don't know with Win 8.1.

Visual Studio's Activity Log is not much help.

thanks
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to trace your package with [Runtime Flow](http://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) (commercial, developed by me, 30-day trial). Run monitoring for Visual Studio and set filter to your package .dll.

Comment: I was albe to find and fix the cause of the exception within 5 mins of installing Runtime Flow and watching the videos. Excellent product and very useful.